# Как сделать волну на фоне на css

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такую волну как на фоне этого изображения? Можно ли это сделать только с помощью стилей

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно вынести волну с SVG, а затем поставить на фон в `:before`. Да, только с помощью стилей.

Пример:

```css
.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #22ccff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1440 320'%3E%3Cpath fill='%230099ff' fill-opacity='1' d='M0,32L80,48C160,64,320,96,480,138.7C640,181,800,235,960,229.3C1120,224,1280,160,1360,128L1440,96L1440,320L1360,320C1280,320,1120,320,960,320C800,320,640,320,480,320C320,320,160,320,80,320L0,320Z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Волну скорее всего можете забрать из макета (вряд ли это не вектор). Можно сгенерировать сервисами по типу GetVawes...